# Terraform azurerm_windows_function_app ip_restrictions issues

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, ip-restrictions

Using resource azurerm_windows_function_app, I am trying to use the ip_restriction block in site_config however upon plan/apply it errors as apparently optional values are required.

All i want to achieve is to Deny all traffic unless from a network/subnet.

The documentation (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_function_app) states this is possible.

I am using the latest provider version and the latest Terraform version.

`Terraform v1.3.7 on windows_amd64 + provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v3.38.0 + provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template v2.2.0`

Code block uploaded to here https://codebeautify.org/cs/c433a9

Doing an apply on the above I get

`Error: Incorrect attribute value type │ │   on main.tf line 181, in resource "azurerm_windows_function_app" "windows_function_app": │  181:       ip_restriction = [ { │  182:         action = "Deny" │  183:         virtual_network_subnet_id =     data.terraform_remote_state.netsec_outputs.outputs.vnet_subnets_info["APIM"].id │  184:         name = "APIM Access" │  185:         priority = 1 │  186:       } ] │     ├──────────────── │     │ data.terraform_remote_state.netsec_outputs.outputs.vnet_subnets_info["APIM"].id is     "/subscriptions/0000000--00000000--00000000/resourceGroups/prt-sit-2-netsec-    01/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/prt-sit-2-vnet/subnets/apim" │ │ Inappropriate value for attribute "ip_restriction": element 0: attributes "headers",  "ip_address", and "service_tag" are required`

What i expect to happen is it completes a plan and wishes to add the ip_restriction block.

Comment: Please add your TF code to your question (no need for external link). Also you have to provide values for all the values used in the code, e.g. `local.windowsfa`.

Answer (score 0):

Worked around my issue. If you use a dynamic block with only the elements you wish to use it passes and validates